# SimpleHtmlDom Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, exists

I'm using SIMPLEHTMLDOM class and when i'm writing this code:

```
$html -> find(".search_results div table")
```

it shows this error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object"
The reason is because this div doesn't exists, but I dont know how to check if he exists or no: I tried isset but it shows this error "Can't use method return value in write context" and I tried is_object, but it still shows "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object", how can I fix that?

Comment: What is `$html`? Show us the part where you assign a value to it.

Comment: This is not the problem, I wrote the problem. I'll repeat: there is no div ".search_results". Thereupon, it says the error "fetal error: call to member function find() on a non-object", how can I check if it exists or no?

Comment: You're calling `find` on `$html`, and the error message says it is not an object. This has nothing to do with the css selector you specified.